# MongoDB nested aggregation lookup

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I wont to connect two collection so as to `workouts._id` had an assigned value `exercise.name`.

first collection "workouts":

```
{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "60ffbd531b1cba41e8a7fde3"
        },
        "id_user": {
            "$oid": "60fd50ee1e9d064a5cee0bec"
        },
        "date": {
            "$date": "2021-05-20T22:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "name": "wielki bicek",
        "workouts": [{
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "60e07e588a2f1946f895475f"
            },
            "parts": [{
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "60ffbd531b1cba41e8a7fde5"
                },
                "weight": "30",
                "repeating": "10"
            }]
        }, {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "60e07e588a2f1946f895475f"
            },
            "parts": [{
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "60ffbd531b1cba41e8a7fde9"
                },
                "weight": "30",
                "repeating": "10"
            }, {
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "60ffbd531b1cba41e8a7fdea"
                },
                "weight": "30",
                "repeating": "10"
            }]
        }],
        "__v": 0
    }
```

second collection "exercises":

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60e07e588a2f1946f895475f"
    },
    "name": "Wyciskanie sztangi",
    "image": "uploads\\2021-07-03T15-12-24.173Z-test.gif",
    "type": "force",
    "groupMuscle": {
        "$oid": "60daf099c1aaa20b4cfdf0fa"
    },
    "instruction": "Opierając tułów znazewnątrz.",
    "__v": 0
}
```

I have one collection that I want to run nested aggregation on this, but I don't know how to run this operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$unwind` unwind workouts
- `$lookup` lookpup exercises
- `$addFileds` get first item
- `$addFileds` get only name field
- `$project` remove useless field
- `$group` group by original id

```
db.workouts.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$workouts"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "exercises",
      pipeline: [
        {
          "$project": {
            name: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "localField": "workouts._id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "names"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "workouts.i": {
        "$first": "$names"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "workouts.name": "$workouts.i.name"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "names": 0,
      "workouts.i": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "id_user": "$id_user",
        "date": "$date",
        "name": "$name"
      },
      "workouts": {
        $push: "$workouts"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TTRN9CmrFZj)